# Two Almost Identical Functions. One function is queued with Queue.Jquery effects aren't working on the queued function. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So long story short.. I am working on my first portfolio. I'm using Jquery to manipulate my text. I want the text to fade in, out in Order. For some reason when I use queue to load the function the text in the span tag in the queued function isn't fading in, out. I'm not sure why this is. Any ideas? Edit: It works now. I have no more issues. I added clearQueue() to the ChangeInterests2 function. Updated the code to show this.

```
function interestsTimer2() {



    window.setTimeout(changeInterests2, 2500);


 }


function interestsTimer() {

    $("span .interests").fadeOut(2000);
    window.setTimeout(changeInterests, 2500);
    $("span .interests").fadeIn(5000);

 }


function changeInterests2() {

    $("span .interests").html("craft Beer.")
    $("span .interests").clearQueue();
    $("span .interests" ).fadeIn(5000);


 }



function changeInterests() {


    $("span .interests").html("hiking Seattle.");

 }


interestsTimer();

$("span .interests").fadeOut(2000).queue(function () {

     interestsTimer2();

})
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle??

Comment: What does "use queue to load the function" mean?

Comment: I'm using .queue to queue up my interestsTimer2 function, that's simply what I mean.

Comment: Maybe it's because the function in queue is altering the queue for `$("span .interests")` before it can resolve itself?  Does it work if you anchor your delay off a different element?

Comment: @Razzakun Did any of the answers work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queue itself seems to get jammed with this code.  If I add `.clearQueue()` before the delay starts it cleans up... something.

This code can be run continuously on a page with a div, but without `.clearQueue()` it will not(although it will run once).

```
$("div:first").clearQueue().delay(3000).queue(function () {

     console.log("Works?");

});
```

I hope someone else here understands the queue better than I, but I offer this for now.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function interestsTimer2() {

  alert('this func is called!');
  $("span .interests").stop().fadeOut(2000);
  window.setTimeout(changeInterests2, 2500);
  $("span .interests").stop().fadeIn(5000);


}


function interestsTimer() {

  $("span .interests").fadeOut(2000);
  window.setTimeout(changeInterests, 2500);
  $("span .interests").fadeIn(5000);

}


function changeInterests2() {

  $("span .interests").html("craft Beer.");

}



function changeInterests() {


  $("span .interests").html("hiking Seattle.");

}


interestsTimer();

$("span .interests").delay(3000).queue(function() {

  interestsTimer2();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <span>
      <a href="#" class="interests">one</a>
    </span>
    <span>
      <a href="#" class="interests">two</a>
    </span>
    <span>
      <a href="#" class="interests">three</a>
    </span>
    <span>
      <a href="#" class="interests">four</a>
    </span>
    <span>
      <a href="#" class="interests">five</a>
    </span>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Queue seems to be working in this example. Maybe the HTML you have does not match what's in your script.

Comment: That isn't the issue. I'm trying to figure out why the Jquery effects in the second function aren't working.

Comment: I think the animations maybe running regardless of the timers. Try with the stop() method.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issues by adding clearQueue() to the ChangeInterests2 function before fadeIn(); Thanks to Grallen as your reply helped me find the answer.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped.